# How to extract with REGEXP the specific combination in BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have a long text, here is the part of it: *"placement":1,"protocols":[2,3,5,6]},"secure":1*

And I need to extract the list of protocols, so the result will be only [2,3,5,6].

I was using **REGEXP_EXTRACT(text, r'"protocols":([^"]+)')**, but the result is always different: sometimes it is only *[2,3,5,6]* and sometimes it takes more: *[2,3,5,6]},*

How to build my REGEXP so the result will be always only the list in brackets?

Comment: is your long text a valid JSON?

Comment: Try to use `"protocols":(\[[^]]+])`

Comment: @Pentium10 yes, it is a json

Comment: Please use JSON functions and not REGEXP if it a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(text, r'"protocols"\s*:\s*(\[[^][]+])')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FcBATu/2)

To get the contents of `protocols` without the brackets, move the grouping boundaries a bit inward:

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(text, r'"protocols"\s*:\s*\[([^][]+)]')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FcBATu/3).

**Details**

- `"protocols"` - a literal text
- `\s*:\s*`  - a colon enclosed with zero or more whitespace
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^][]+` - one or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.